# In python using ctypes, when calling a function in a dll, how do I pass a char**?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have the following code in a dll written in C which I need to call from python:

```
// get_name will allocate a char* and place it in out_name
void get_name(char** out_name)
{
    const char* the_name = "George";
    size_t the_name_size = strlen(the_name);
    *out_name = (char*)malloc(the_name_size+1);
    strncpy(*out_name, the_name, the_name_size+1);
}

// free_name will deallocate the pointer returned by get_name
void free_name(char* name_to_free)
{
    free(name_to_free);
}
```

In a C program this code would be called:

```
char* name = 0;
get_name(&name);
// ... do something with name
free_name(name);
```

Here is what I tried in python:

```
from ctypes import *

the_name_lib = CDLL(path_to_dll)
the_name_lib.get_name.argtypes(POINTER(POINTER(c_char_p)))
the_name_lib.free_name.argtypes(POINTER(c_char_p))

name_from_dll = c_char_p()
name_from_dll_pointer = pointer(answer)
the_name_lib.get_name(name_from_dll_pointer)
the_name_lib.free_name(name_from_dll)
```

This crashes inside the dll.

Comment: `c_char_p` is a `char *` and `argtypes` should be assigned a tuple or list of ctypes types. Use `get_name.argtypes = (POINTER(c_char_p),);` `free_name.argtypes = (c_char_p,)`.  Pass it as `get_name(byref(name_from_dll))` and free it as `free_name(name_from_dll)`.

Comment: thanks @eryksun, this indeed works. Please post as a complete answer and I will approve.